# FileSystemWatcher OnCreated only firing for first file of multiple files copied

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I have a `FileSystemWatcher` that I would like to fire an `OnCreated event` ***for every folder copied into the watched directory***. Several folders will be copied into this watched directory at once,  manually.

Currently it is only firing the `event` for the first folder copied.
So if I'm watching folder X and select folders A,B,C in windows explorer and copy them into X, `OnCreated` is fired for A but not B or C.

This is my code that I'm using to set up the `FileSystemWatcher`:

```
watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher(watchPath);            
watcher.InternalBufferSize = 32768;
watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | 
                       NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;


watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

and here is my `OnCeated` method

```
void OnCeated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{            
    XDocument xmlDoc = BeginImport(e.FullPath); 
}
```

Any idea **why this is only firing the event for the first folder** copied into the watched directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx):

> The Windows operating system notifies your component of file changes in a buffer created by the FileSystemWatcher. **If there are many changes in a short time, the buffer can overflow. This causes the component to lose track of changes in the directory, and it will only provide blanket notification**. Increasing the size of the buffer with the InternalBufferSize property is expensive, as it comes from non-paged memory that cannot be swapped out to disk, so keep the buffer as small yet large enough to not miss any file change events. **To avoid a buffer overflow, use the NotifyFilter and IncludeSubdirectories properties so you can filter out unwanted change notifications.**

It seems to be an internal limitation.

I believe the act of pasting all three folder at once is considered "many changes in a short time" -- can you use the [NotifyFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter.aspx) and leave out some events?

Comment: +1  @ELG maybe track the date of the last processed file and then process any files with a date gt.

Comment: That was it,  thanks!   I set the buffer to max allowed (64k),  turned off include subdirectories, and filtered for only CreationTime and DirectoryName,  and it processes at least 50 directories at a time.

Comment: It can also be helpful to create your own buffer; have a concurrent queue that you add to when notified, and then act on that queue later. As long as the work you want done based on file changes takes longer than the work of adding an object representing it to the queue (which is very often the case), this makes missed file changes less likely.